# Use the Gauss-Laguerre quadrature to approximate an integral in R

Tags: r, math, optimization, integral

I am using the Gauss-Laguerre quadrature to approximate the following integral

[image: First formula]

I wrote the function in R

```
int.gl<-function(x)
{
 x^(-0.2)/(x+100)*exp(-100/x)
}
```

First, I used `integrate()` function to get the "true" value, which I double check with Wolfram Alpha

```
integrate(int.gl, lower = 0, upper = Inf)$value
[1] 1.627777
```

Then, I used `glaguerre.quadrature()` function

```
rule<-glaguerre.quadrature.rules(64, alpha = 0, normalized = F)[[64]]
glaguerre.quadrature(int.gl, lower = 0, upper = Inf, rule = rule, weighted = F)
[1] 0.03610346
```

Clearly, the result is far away from the true value. At that time, I thought I had to transform this function to include a e^(-x) term. So, let X = 1/Y. I obtained a different formula but the same integral

[image: Second formula]

In the same manner, I used the following R code

```
int.gl2<-function(x)
{
 x^(-0.8)/(1+100*x)*exp(-100*x)
}
integrate(int.gl2, lower = 0, upper = Inf)$value
[1] 1.627777
glaguerre.quadrature(int.gl2, lower = 0, upper = Inf, rule = rule, weighted = F)
[1] 0.03937068
```

Well, two different values. Does the Gauss-Laguerre quadrature have trouble in finding this integral? Is there any other Gauss-type quadrature can help find this integral?

**Note:** I have to use Gauss-type quadrature since I am trying to find MLEs of some parameters for a customized distribution. For simplicity, I just fixed these parameters(these constants in the integral). However, `integrate()` function seems to be less "robust" than `glaguerre.quadrature()` function. (`integrate()` returns divergent error when optimizing the log-likelihood).

**EDIT 1**

According to Hans. W's comment, I check the use of `glaguerre.quadrature` with the following example. Suppose we wanna find the following integral

```
int.gl3<-function(x)
{
 ((x+100)/(x+200))^0.2*exp(-5*x)
}

glaguerre.quadrature(int.gl3, lower = 0, upper = Inf, rule = rule, weighted = F)
[1] 0.1741448
integrate(int.gl3, lower = 0, upper = Inf)$value
[1] 0.1741448
```

It seems like the use of `glaguerre.quadrature` is correct.

Let's check the transformation now. I transform this integral, by letting 100Y=X, such that it includes exp(-x).

```
int.gl4<-function(x)
{
 0.01^0.2*x^(-0.8)/(1+x)*exp(-x)
}
integrate(int.gl4, lower = 0, upper = Inf)$value
[1] 1.627777
glaguerre.quadrature(int.gl4, lower = 0, upper = Inf, rule = rule, weighted = F)
[1] 0.9621667
```

The result is more close to the true value but not exactly equal.

**EDIT 2**

Here is my complete example

[Integration and false convergence of optimization in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50472929/6867848)

Comment: I assume your use of `gaussquad::glaguerre.quadrature` is probably and the transformation of the integral is certainly incorrect; e.g. the exponential term must be `exp(-x)`. I tried `pracma::gaussLaguerre` with the corrected integrand and I failed, too. It seems like this function is converging to zero much too slowly for the in R available Gauss-Laguerre implementations.

Comment: @HansW. As you mentioned, it was improved but still not that good.

Comment: Your transformed function `int.gl4` is now converging rapidly enough to be handled by `integrate`. Even integrating it over the interval `[0, 100]` is sufficient for double precision: `integrate(int.gl4, 0, 100)` will return "1.627777 with absolute error < 2.8e-05".

Comment: @HansW. For this example, yes, `integrate` can handle this integral perfectly. However, I intend to use Gauss-type quadrature which, I think, is more robust than `integrate` because `integrate` was more likely to returns divergent error when I did optimization to find MLEs. For simplicity, I fixed those parameters. That is the reason why you can see constants in the integral.

Comment: As long as you do not provide a relevant example, it is difficult to help you. Basically, for integrating a badly converging function with Gauss-Laguerre, you will need many, many more nodes than those 64 you compute here. Saying that a procedure giving wrong results is better than one that is not robust -- that is a bit of a strange consideration in my eyes.

Comment: @HansW. Thank you for your response. I just edited my question and provided a complete example in another question.